# merge multiple nested array of nested objects in es6?

Tags: javascript

i have an array like this:

```
[
  {
    data: [
      { a: "a", b: "b" },
      { x: "x", y: "y" },
    ],
  },
  {
    data: [
      { c: "c", d: "d" },
      { z: "z", f: "f" },
    ],
  },
  {
    data: [
      { d: "d", e: "e" },
      { g: "g", h: "h" },
    ],
  },
];
```

now i want to have all items in data in one array, an end result like this:

```
[
  { a: "a", b: "b" },
  { x: "x", y: "y" },
  { c: "c", d: "d" },
  { z: "z", f: "f" },
  { d: "d", e: "e" },
  { g: "g", h: "h" },
];
```

i don't wanna use lodash which i found on suggested questions, hope to use only es6

Answer (score 1):

Simply, using [Array.prototype.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), you can make all items in data in one array.

```js
const input = [
  {
    data: [
      { a: "a", b: "b" },
      { x: "x", y: "y" },
    ],
  },
  {
    data: [
      { c: "c", d: "d" },
      { z: "z", f: "f" },
    ],
  },
  {
    data: [
      { d: "d", e: "e" },
      { g: "g", h: "h" },
    ],
  },
];

const output = input.flatMap((item) => item.data);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe are looking for this:

```js
const params = [
  {
    data: [
      { a: "a", b: "b" },
      { x: "x", y: "y" },
    ],
  },
  {
    data: [
      { c: "c", d: "d" },
      { z: "z", f: "f" },
    ],
  },
  {
    data: [
      { d: "d", e: "e" },
      { g: "g", h: "h" },
    ],
  },
];

const result = params.map(p => p.data).flat();
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array reduce method.

```
let a = [
  {
    data: [
      { a: "a", b: "b" },
      { x: "x", y: "y" },
    ],
  },
  {
    data: [
      { c: "c", d: "d" },
      { z: "z", f: "f" },
    ],
  },
  {
    data: [
      { d: "d", e: "e" },
      { g: "g", h: "h" },
    ],
  },
];

let ret = a.reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c.data), []);
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = [
  {
    data: [
      { a: "a", b: "b" },
      { x: "x", y: "y" },
    ],
  },
  {
    data: [
      { c: "c", d: "d" },
      { z: "z", f: "f" },
    ],
  },
  {
    data: [
      { d: "d", e: "e" },
      { g: "g", h: "h" },
    ],
  },
];

let final =[]
let newData = data.map(el => el.data.map(e => final.push(e)))
console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

May use reduce with spread-operator:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    data: [
      { a: "a", b: "b" },
      { x: "x", y: "y" },
    ],
  },
  {
    data: [
      { c: "c", d: "d" },
      { z: "z", f: "f" },
    ],
  },
  {
    data: [
      { d: "d", e: "e" },
      { g: "g", h: "h" },
    ],
  },
];

const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, rec) => [...acc, ...rec.data], [])
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, you might want to edit in an explanation why your solution works, and what it does. As it stands it's just a slab of code without much explanation even if it does seem correct.